# Substring Sum Set

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic, array

#### Introduction

Let's observe this array: `[3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2]`.

Each element displays the length of the substring which must be summed up. Let's take a look at the first element of the above array:

```
[3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2]
 ^
```

The element at the first index is **3**, so we now take a substring of length three with the same index as the starting position:

```
[3, 2, 4]
```

When summed up, this results into **9**, so the first element of the **substring sum set** is `9`.

We do this for all the elements in the array:

```
3 -> [3, 2, 4]
2 -> [2, 4]
4 -> [4, 1, 1, 5]
1 -> [1]
1 -> [1]
5 -> [5, 1, 2]
1 -> [1]
2 -> [2]
```

You can see that the number **5** is a bit of a weird case. That number exceeds the length of the array:

```
[3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2]
                ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
```

We'll ignore everything that exceeds the array, so we just use `[5, 1, 2]`.

The last step is to sum everything up:

```
[3, 2, 4]     -> 9
[2, 4]        -> 6
[4, 1, 1, 5]  -> 11
[1]           -> 1
[1]           -> 1
[5, 1, 2]     -> 8
[1]           -> 1
[2]           -> 2
```

And that is the array that needs to be outputted:

```
[9, 6, 11, 1, 1, 8, 1, 2]
```

#### The Task

Given an non-empty array with positive (non-zero) integers, output the **substring sum set**. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the smallest number of bytes wins!

#### Test cases

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> [1, 5, 12, 9, 5]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3] -> [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 6, 3]
[5, 1, 2, 4, 1] -> [13, 1, 6, 5, 1]
[1] -> [1]
```

Comment: I think you mean "sub-list", not "substring". There's no strings.

Comment: @mbomb007 I think substring has the same meaning here as in the longest common substring problem, i.e., a subsequence whose elements are adjacent. Data types aside, a string is just a finite sequence of elements of an alphabet set (in this case, the positive integers).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṫJḣ"ḅ1
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmrSuG4oyLhuIUx&input=&args=WzMsIDIsIDQsIDEsIDEsIDUsIDEsIDJd) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmrSuG4oyLhuIUxCsOH4oKsRw&input=&args=WzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDVdLCBbMywgMywgMywgMywgMywgMywgMywgM10sIFs1LCAxLCAyLCA0LCAxXSwgWzFd).

#### How it works

```
ṫJḣ"ḅ1  Main link. Argument: A (array)

 J      Index; yield the 1-based indices of A.
ṫ       Tail; map k to the postfix of A that begins with the k-th element.
  ḣ"    Vectorized head; for each k in A, truncate the corr. postfix to length k.
    ḅ1  Convert the resulting slices from base 1 to integer.
```

Answer (score 11):

## Python, 40 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x and[sum(x[:x[0]])]+f(x[1:])
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/cw3R0H).

Comment: I *figured* there would be a golfier recursive solution, but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 11):

## Excel, 21 bytes

`=SUM(OFFSET(A1,,,A1))`

Open a new spreadsheet, put the test values in column A. Enter the formula in B1 and double click the cell handle to ride the range.

Comment: I'd give you a second upvote for teaching me about that double-click trick if I could.

Comment: While it works it's a bit of cheating as execution requires manual input.

Comment: @user3819867 not significantly more than most program execution, I'd argue. Perhaps it would be even more comparable if you save a spreadsheet only containing the formula in B1  - then open, add the data to column A, and double-click the handle on B1 to execute. YMMV of course.

Answer (score 7):

### Python 3, 47 bytes

```
lambda X:[sum(X[i:i+k])for i,k in enumerate(X)]
```

Pretty straightforward implementation. Python's default behavior for slices that go past the end of the list was *very* convenient here.

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, <s>34</s>, 33 bytes

```
f l@(x:y)=sum(take x l):f y
f x=x
```

One byte saved by nimi.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript ES6, 50 bytes

```js
a=>a.map((e,i)=>a.slice(i,i+e).reduce((a,b)=>a+b))
```

Pretty self-explanatory. It `map`s over each element in the array, getting the `slice` from that `i`ndex through the index plus that `e`lement's value, and `reduce`ing by adding.

```js
f=
  a=>a.map((e,i)=>a.slice(i,i+e).reduce((a,b)=>a+b))

;[
  [3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,],
  [5, 1, 2, 4, 1],
  [1]
].forEach(function(test){
  document.getElementById('p').textContent += test + ' => ' + f(test) + '\n';
});
```

```html
<pre id="p"></pre>
```

Answer (score 4):

## J, 11 bytes

```
+/@{."_1]\.
```

#### Usage

```
   f =: +/@{."_1]\.
   f 3 2 4 1 1 5 1 2
9 6 11 1 1 8 1 2
   f 1 2 3 4 5
1 5 12 9 5
```

#### Explanation

```
+/@{."_1]\.  Input: A
        ]\.  Get each suffix of A from longest to shortest
   {."_1     For each value in A, take that many values from its corresponding suffix
+/@          Sum that group of values taken from that suffix
             Return the sums
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 45

`reduce` beaten again!

```js
a=>a.map((v,i)=>eval(a.slice(i,v+i).join`+`))
```

```js
F=
a=>a.map((v,i)=>eval(a.slice(i,v+i).join`+`))

;[[3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,],
  [5, 1, 2, 4, 1],
  [1]].forEach(t=>console.log(t+' -> '+F(t)))
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can remove the `f=`, just as in [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86229/substring-sum-set#86234).

Comment: @LarsW right, the `f=` is already not counted in the 45 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica <s>60</s> 55 bytes

```
Tr@Take[#,UpTo@#&@@#]&/@Drop[#,t-1]~Table~{t,Length@#}&
```

eg

```
f = %; f /@ {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {5, 1, 2, 4, 1}, {1}}

(*    {{1, 5, 12, 9, 5}, {9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 6, 3}, {13, 1, 6, 5, 1}, {1}}    *)
```

Thanks @MartinEnder for shaving off 5 bytes :)

Comment: Here is an idea to avoid the table: `#+Tr@Take[x=Rest@x,UpTo[#-1]]&/@(x=#)&` Still not sure it's optimal but it saves 17 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 38 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
\d+
$*
M!&`\b1(1)*(?<-1>,1+)*
M%`1
¶
,
```

Input and output are comma-separated lists.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYApcZCsKJCoKTSEmYFxiMSgxKSooPzwtMT4sMSspKgpNJWAxCsK2Ciw&input=MSwyLDMsNCw1CjMsMiw0LDEsMSw1LDEsMgozLDMsMywzLDMsMywzLDMKNSwxLDIsNCwxCjE) (The first line enables a linefeed-separated test suite.)

Answer (score 3):

### 05AB1E, <s>11</s> 8 bytes

```
[D¬£Oˆ¦Ž
```

**Explanation**

```
[         # infinite loop
 D        # duplicate current list
  ¬       # get head of list
   £      # get that many elements from list
    O     # sum
     ˆ    # add to global array
      ¦   # remove first element of list
       Ž  # break if stack is empty
          # implicitly push and print global array
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=W0TCrMKjT8uGwqbFvQ&input=WzMsIDIsIDQsIDEsIDEsIDUsIDEsIDJd)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
.es:Qk+b
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.es%3AQk%2Bb&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D%0A%5B3%2C3%2C3%2C3%2C3%2C3%2C3%2C3%5D%0A%5B5%2C1%2C2%2C4%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%5D&debug=0)

Translation of [El's answer in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86230/48934).

Answer (score 2):

## Erlang, 69 bytes

```
f(A)->put(1,1),L=lists,[L:sum(L:sublist(A,put(1,get(1)+1),X))||X<-A].
```

Erlang's higher-order functions for lists do not receive the index of the current element. This uses the process dictionary to set the index of the current element.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, <s>12</s> 7 bytes

```
FKo>i<s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=FKo%3Ei%3Cs&input=%5B3%2C+2%2C+4%2C+1%2C+1%2C+5%2C+1%2C+2%5D)

```
        - o = 0
F       - for i in input:
  o     -    o+=1
   >    -    input[o:]
    i<  -   ^[:i]
      s -  sum(^)
```

Answer (score 2):

## VBA, 160 bytes

```
Function e(g())
Dim h()
k=LBound(g)
l=UBound(g)
ReDim h(k To l)
On Error Resume Next
For i=k To l
For j=i To i+g(i)-1
h(i)=h(i)+g(j)
Next
Next
e=h
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Matricks](https://github.com/jediguy13/Matricks), 25 bytes

Yay, finally a challenge I don't need new features for!

```
md{z:l-g:c;+c;q:c;};:1:l;
```

Run with: `python matricks.py substring.txt [[<input>]] 0`

Explanation:

```
m                  :1:l;   #loop over entire input
                           #set each value to...
 d{               }        #the sum of...
   z:l-g:c:+c;q:c;         #the input cropped to
                           #the length of the value in the cell
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
ms<~tQ
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ms%3C~tQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B3%2C+2%2C+4%2C+1%2C+1%2C+5%2C+1%2C+2%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%5D%0A%5B3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%5D%0A%5B5%2C+1%2C+2%2C+4%2C+1%5D%0A%5B1%5D&debug=0)

This is a different solution from any others so far. It loops over the input, slicing an summing the initial values, then removing the first element of the stored input, and repeat.

Explanation:

```
ms<~tQ
ms<~tQdQ    Implicit variable introduction
            Implicit: Q = eval(input())
m      Q    Map d over the input, Q
  <  Qd     Take the first d elements of Q
 s          Sum them
   ~tQ      Afterwards, set Q to the tail of Q, removing the first element.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>17</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
fGy+!-R0<G*!s
```

#### Explanation

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P829UltRN8jAxl1Lsfj//2hjHQUjHQUTHQVDMDIFk0axAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyHCmyvNu1JbUTfIwMZbS7GYyyXk//9oQx0FIx0FYx0FEx0F01iuaGMwBx0BJUx1FCBqgQoNgXzDWAA) (code modified to handle several inputs).

```
f     % Take input implicitly. Indices of nonzero elements: this gives [1 2 ... n]
      % where n is input size
G     % Push input again
y     % Push a copy of [1 2 ... n]
+     % Add. Gives [a+1 b+2...] where [a b...] is the input
!     % Transpose into a column vector
-     % Subtraction with broadcast. Gives 2D array
R     % Keep upper triangular part, making the rest of entries 0
0<    % True for negative entries. Each row corresponds to a substring sum.
      % For each row, this gives true for the entries of the input that make up
      % that substring sum. Each row is thus a mask to select entries of the input
G     % Push input again
*     % Multiply with broadcast. This multiplies the input times each row
!s    % Sum of each row. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript (using External Library) (66 bytes)

```
n=>_.From(n).Select((v,i)=>_.From(n).Slice(i,i+v).Sum()).ToArray()
```

Link to lib: https://github.com/mvegh1/Enumerable

Code explanation: _.From is loading the input array into the library, which is basically LINQ for js. Then each item in the array is mapped according to the following predicate: Take the input, and slice it from current item index and take that index plus the current item's value. Then Sum up that subsequence. Convert the result to a native JS array and return it

[image]

Comment: Remove the `var ` from the variables, you don't need that in golf. You can also change `.forEach` to `.map` which costs less bytes.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right about var. Thanks! I'll go through this answer again tomorrow. It looks like native JS (es6) kills my solution lol

Comment: Good call on removing var. I also realized another solution which reduces the byte count a lot and is also more intuitive

Answer (score 1):

### F#, <s>84</s> 82 bytes

```
let f(A:int[])=[for i in 0..A.Length-1->Seq.skip i A|>Seq.truncate A.[i]|>Seq.sum]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 39 bytes

```julia
!x=x!=[]?[take(x,x[])|>sum;!x[2:end]]:x
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=IXg9eCE9W10_W3Rha2UoeCx4W10pfD5zdW07IXhbMjplbmRdXTp4Cgpmb3IgeCBpbiAoWzMsMiw0LDEsMSw1LDEsMl0sIFsxLDIsMyw0LDVdLCBbMywzLDMsMywzLDMsMywzXSwgWzUsMSwyLDQsMV0sIFsxXSkKICAgIEBwcmludGYoIiUtMTdzIC0-ICVzXG4iLCB4LCAheCkKZW5k&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) - 79 Bytes

A recursive solution that does not use any of the Array methods:

```
f=([a,...t],n)=>a&&n?a+f(t,n-1):0;g=([a,...t],r=[])=>a?g(t,[...r,a+f(t,a-1)]):r
```

Testing:

```js
f=([a,...t],n)=>a&&n?a+f(t,n-1):0;
g=([a,...t],r=[])=>a?g(t,[...r,a+f(t,a-1)]):r;

[
  [3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,],
  [5, 1, 2, 4, 1],
  [1]
].forEach(a=>console.log(''+g(a)));
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 89 bytes

```
int[]s(List<int>a)=>a.Select((n,i)=>a.GetRange(i,Math.Min(n,a.Count-i)).Sum()).ToArray();
```

**pretty straight forward**

improvement ideas appreciated

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 27 bytes

```
.v|h~l(A:Tc?;A?)b:0&~b.h~+A
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=LnZ8aH5sKEE6VGM_O0E_KWI6MCZ-Yi5ofitB&input=WzM6Mjo0OjE6MTo1OjE6Ml0&args=Wg) or [verify all test cases](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=Ons6MiZ3QE53fWEKLnZ8aH5sKEE6VGM_O0E_KWI6MiZ-Yi5ofitB&input=W1szOjI6NDoxOjE6NToxOjJdOlsxOjI6Mzo0OjVdOlszOjM6MzozOjM6MzozOjNdOls1OjE6Mjo0OjFdOlsxXV0).

#### Explanation

```
  .v           Input = Output = []
|            Or
  h~l          A is a list, its length is the value of the first element of the Input
  (
    A:Tc?        The concatenation of A with another list T results in the Input
  ;            Or
    A?           A = Input
  )
  b:0&         Call recursively on Input minus the first element
  ~b.          Output is the output of that call with an extra element at the beginning
  h~+A         That extra element is the sum of the elements of A
```

Answer (score 1):

### Dyalog APL, 15 bytes

```
{+/¨⍵↑∘⌽¨⌽,\⌽⍵}
```

or

```
{⌽+/¨(-↑¨,\)⌽⍵}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP program, 72 Bytes

```
<?foreach($a=$_GET[a]as$i=>$v)echo array_sum(array_slice($a,$i,$v)),"
";
```

call with `php-cgi -f <filename> 'a[]=3&a[]=2&a[]=4...`

+11 as a function:

```
function f($a){foreach($a as$i=>$v)$r[]=array_sum(array_slice($a,$i,$v));return$r;}
```

+9 without builtins:

```
function p($a){foreach($c=$r=$a as$i=>$v)for($k=$i;$k--;)if(--$a[$k]>0)$r[$k]+=$v;return$r;}
```

($c keeps the original values, $a counts down for each index, $r gets the sums)

-3 as program:

```
<?foreach($a=$r=$c=$_GET[a]as$i=>$v)for($k=$i;$k--;)if(--$c[$k]>0)$r[$k]+=$v;print_r($r);
```

Answer (score 1):

## q (37 bytes)

```
{sum each(til[count x],'x)sublist\:x}
```

Example:

```
q){sum each(til[count x],'x)sublist\:x}3 2 4 1 1 5 1 2
9 6 11 1 1 8 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 63 bytes

```
(defn f[[b & r]](concat[(apply + b(take(dec b)r))](if r(f r))))
```

Uses pattern matching to decompose input argument in to the first and the rest of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

**C#, 94 bytes**

```
Console.Write(String.Join(",",a.Select((v,i)=>a.Skip(i).Take(v).Sum().ToString()).ToArray()));
```

Where a is an int[] that represents the input to be solved.

Comment: you arent allowed to assume a variable is predefined

Comment: The variable a is the input to be solved.